# Will a Java stack pointing to an array use the same amount of memory?

Tags: java

I have a binary tree of `Node`s and want to traverse it. The most common method I'm seeing is a `Stack`, or a `LinkedList`. I've also seen other methods that don't add each `Node` to a Stack/List, and seem to take up almost no memory (they use recursion instead to explore each element).

If I make a `List<Node>` to track each node in the tree, will I be taking up `2*n` the amount of memory? Or, because the objects already exist in the tree, will the List only be a bunch of pointers to Node objects (which exist in the Tree), and therefore don't take up twice the memory?

Test Case:

```
Object objs[] = new Object[40];
/* 
    Initialize the 40 objects here 
*/
List<Object> objTracker = new List<>();
for(int i=0; i<objs.length; i++) {
    objTracker.add(objs[i]);
}
```

Does this now take up 2x the amount of memory, or do all of the `objTrackers` just redirect/point to the objects stored in `objs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only create a new object when using the `new` keyword (generally speaking). Since there's no `new` in `objTracker.add(objs[i]);`, no new objects are created.

Comment: What if I'm keeping track of them in an array? Does a second array of pointers (speaking abstractly, as Java doesn't allow explicitly) to a first array's objects use the same amount of memory as creating a new set of objects in array 2?

Comment: Of course not. If you have a box with a banana in it, and a second box with a note in there that says "see box 1", how many bananas do you have? What if you add more boxes with notes? The only additional things you'll have is the container objects (boxes, arrays, lists) and references (the notes).

Comment: Okay, but with an array creation, I *do* use `new`. As in, `object[] objs = new Object[30];`. I thought that it reserves in memory enough space for 30 slots. If so, why should it take up more space once I start assigning each slot to a `new Object()`?

Comment: You're creating a new array object yes. Then you fill it with references to existing objects. If you fill it with references to new objects, then you have more objects and more space being used.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. That makes sense. Thanks, my class wasn't very focused on the memory and how it looks in the computer.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, stack memory is separate from heap memory. Stack memory is consumed for every method call, but usually this doesn't count as "occupied" memory because it's not managed by GC and because it gets released as soon as the call returns.

In the end, you have to store your objects somewhere. So it's either stack or heap. List and array have comparable space requirements if you're not overallocating their size. In your code, you are not allocating any Nodes - they already exist. You are only allocating space for array / List.

What you are doing with your code is most likely redundant. You can add your elemets to List in the first place. As you have it now, you first store objects in array, then copy them to List. If you have no further uses of `objs`, then `objs` will eventually be garbage collected, leaving only `objTracker` in memory.

Comment: Right...that was just an example to illustrate what I meant. It would definitely be redundant. OK. I wanted to make sure that, if I used a Stack to traverse a binary tree of data, that I wouldn't be duplicating the data. Seems like it will not, which is what I hoped for, but I wanted to be sure before implementation. Thanks!

Comment: He was referring to the `Stack` class, not the internal call stack. Don't start talking about stack allocation here, it'll only be confusing.